# why doesn't communication between two controllers using service work in angular?

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

index.html

```
      <body >
      <p ng-controller="MainCtrl as mv">Hello {{mv.name}}!</p>
      <hr>
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl2 as mv">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name">
      <button ng-click="mv.setN(name)">submit</button><br>
      Hello {{name}}<br>
      Hello {{mv.name}}!

   </div>
  </body>
```

app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('myService', function() {
var my = this;
my.name = "original";
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function(myService) {
var mv = this;
mv.name = myService.name;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl2', function(myService) {
var mv = this;
mv.name = myService.name;

mv.setN = function(a) {
  myService.name = a;

  };
});
```

why isn't the service able to establish communication between controllers  ?I have seen a similar example of factory which is working for communication.
my plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/L5uRHPQiXqQV6K7twHul?p=preview

Comment: its a bit more complex then that to get two controllers to communicate together , maybe go through a tutorial that is explaining just that

Comment: if I remember correctly you have to pass the controllers to the service , and the controllers I think have to have public facing functions that are designed to return responses

Comment: it would if you maintained object references and not convert to primitves http://plnkr.co/edit/C1yoKjKJMXkFIvswUGUo?p=preview

Comment: golden rule...always have a dot in ng-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/cTqJImTLdDwPzGsKxN6W?p=preview

Always use `Object` to share models. Your service should be changed to:

```
app.service('myService',function(){
  var my=this;
  my.n = {
    name: 'paven'
  };
  my.setN=function(a){
      my.n.name=a;
      console.log("name change to "+my.n.name);
  }
});
```